# Suggestion on hierarchy visualisation tool (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, hierarchy

I have got a set of data that goes by hierarchy. For argument sake, let's say this is the top level:

[image: header]

The user should be able to drill down on one of the boxes to explore the data. When clicked, the user sees the second level of data:

[image: subheader]

Alternatively, the second level of data can totally cover the first level (but have a breadcrumb that shows the drill down journey):

[image: subheader]

I am hoping to be able to implement such visualisation tool on ASP.net (i.e. web). Does anyone have a suggestion on a suitable JS / extension plugin?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jsTree jquery plugin. It gives very nice interactive UI in hierarchical level. It provides support like drag & drop support, inline edit, create and delete etc.

You can get it from https://www.jstree.com/. It is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I have settled on Treant.js in the end :)